# DataTables Dynamic Column headers

Tags: jquery, struts2, datatables

I am using the Datatables library with server side implementation in Struts2.
I am able to get the table contents using Ajax call. But the headers are fixed. Is there any way I can load the header labels from server side, like that of the content.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="demo">
        <table id="example" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="80px">Address</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th width="15%">Town</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from
                        server</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this jQuery dataTable plugin?

Comment: @dcodesmith Yes, the same.
datatables.net

Comment: Are the column headers always going to be the same?

Comment: No, every time it populates data from different tables. Hence different headers is needed. In the examples it is hardcoded. I want to set the header in the same way like server side handling of data(ajax call).

Comment: Ok, that is possible but then you'll be creating the table from scratch every time. And you'll have to pass in the column headers too. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<s:if>` tag to add condition inside your `<thead>`tag depending on your action. For example, if your actions are sample1.action and has firstname and lastname headers while sample2.action has country and nationality headers.

here's a sample code

```
<thead>
        <s:if test="#context['struts.actionMapping'].name=='sample1.action'">
            <tr>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th >Lastname</th>
                </tr>
         </s:if>
        <s:elseif test="#context['struts.actionMapping'].name=='sample2.action'">
            <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th >Nationality</th>
                </tr>
         </s:elseif>
</thead>
```